# In Xamarin.Forms.UWP, Unable to set Automation ID to custom control, if not used SetNativeControl() method

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am creating a custom control in Xamarin.Forms which is inherited from TemplatedView and using the application in all three platforms. For testing purposes, I need to set Automation ID for all native controls.

Usually, by using AutomationPeer we can set Automation ID to native UWP control from the UWP renderer project. But, in my custom control, I get this. Control is null always.

So, I can’t set Automation ID in UWP renderer class as Forms TemplatedView is a FrameworkElement in UWP.

My query is,

1. How to get a native element (this.Control) in UWP renderer project for Xamarin.Forms TemplatedView.
2. How to set Automation Id to native UWP control if this.Control is null.

The code snippet is provided below:

```
class FormsCustomLayout : TemplatedView
     {
         public static readonly BindableProperty InputViewProperty =
             BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InputView), typeof(View), typeof(FormsCustomLayout), null, BindingMode.Default, null, OnInputViewChanged);
    
         private static void OnInputViewChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
         {
             (bindable as FormsCustomLayout).OnInputViewChanged(oldValue, newValue);
         }
    
         private void OnInputViewChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
         {
             var oldView = (View)oldValue;
             if (oldView != null)
             {
                 if (this.contentGrid.Children.Contains(oldView))
                 {
                     oldView.SizeChanged -= OnInputViewSizeChanged;
                     oldView.BindingContext = null;
                     this.contentGrid.Children.Remove(oldView);
                 }
             }
    
             var newView = (View)newValue;
             if (newView != null)
             {
                 newView.SizeChanged += OnInputViewSizeChanged;
                 newView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
                 newView.HeightRequest = 60;
                  this.contentGrid.Children.Add(newView);
             }
         }
    
         private void OnInputViewSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
    
         }
    
         public  View InputView
         {
             get { return (View)GetValue(InputViewProperty); }
             set { SetValue(InputViewProperty, value); }
         }
    
         internal void UpdateText(object text)
         {
             this.Text = (string)text;
         }
    
         private readonly Grid contentGrid = new Grid();
    
         public FormsCustomLayout()
         {
             this.ControlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(StackLayout));
             ((StackLayout)Children[0]).Children.Add(this.contentGrid);
             if (InputView != null)
             {
                 this.contentGrid.Children.Add(InputView);
             }
         }
    
         internal string Text { get; private set; }
     }
```

The custom renderer code snippet is provided below:

```
class FormsCustomLayoutRenderer : ViewRenderer<FormsCustomLayout, FrameworkElement>
     {
         /// <summary>
         /// Method that is called when the automation id is set.
         /// </summary>
         /// <param name="id">The automation id.</param>
         protected override void SetAutomationId(string id)
         {
             if (this.Control == null)
             {
                 base.SetAutomationId(id);
             }
             else
             {
                 this.SetAutomationPropertiesAutomationId(id);
                 this.Control.SetAutomationPropertiesAutomationId(id);
             }
         }
    
         /// <summary>
         /// Provide automation peer for the control
         /// </summary>
         /// <returns>The TextInputLayout view automation peer.</returns>
         protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
         {
             if (this.Control == null)
             {
                 return new FormsCustomLayoutAutomationPeer(this);
             }
    
             return new FormsCustomLayoutAutomationPeer(this.Control);
         }
    
         protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FormsCustomLayout> e)
         {
             base.OnElementChanged(e);
             var element = e.NewElement;           
         }           
     }
     internal class FormsCustomLayoutAutomationPeer : FrameworkElementAutomationPeer
     {
         /// <summary>
         /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FormsCustomLayoutRenderer"/> class.
         /// </summary>
         /// <param name="owner">FormsCustomLayout View control</param>
         public FormsCustomLayoutAutomationPeer(FrameworkElement owner) : base(owner)
         {
         }
    
         /// <summary>
         /// Describe the control type
         /// </summary>
         /// <returns>The control type.</returns>
         protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore()
         {
             return AutomationControlType.Custom;
         }
    
         /// <summary>
         /// Describe the class name.
         /// </summary>
         /// <returns>The Class Name.</returns>
         protected override string GetClassNameCore()
         {
             return "FormsCustomLayout";
         }
     }
```

Demo sample attached here: [FormsCustomControl](https://github.com/Eswaran17392/Test/tree/master/FormsCustomControl/FormsCustomControl)

Please share your idea or solution to set Automation ID.

Regards,

Bharathiraja.

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your code, but perhaps you are attempting to access the control before it has been fully laid out? Please do the following test: add a button on the page. When button is pressed, call `SetAutomationId`. Put a breakpoint (or output to debug) to see if `this.Control` is null or not, when you press the button. Comment here with whether it is still null during that button. (Everything visible will have been created before you can push the button. I'm expecting that it will no longer be null.) This may help someone guide you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  But, we are using custom control in xamarin.forms and can't get native control of uwp in renderer.  In that case, how to set Automation ID to native UWP control.?

Comment: *"can't get native control of uwp in renderer"* - Again, this means you are attempting to access the control "too early" in the layout process. Solving this is a bit complicated. You have to find a way to *delay* running the code that needs to use `this.Control`, until it exists (is not `null`). Sorry, I don't have time to figure out and explain exactly how to do this.